# how to import password protected excel sheet in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

```
Ecode   Employee Name   PunchDate   First  Second  Worktime
  194   Nilesh Darji    2015-04-03  10:20  17:20   07:00
                        2015-05-03  10:20  11:20   07:00
                                    11:25  02:00      
                                    02:20  17:20
```

i have a this kind of excel sheet which is password protected.

and i want to use the following class and snippet code

```
require_once 'readernew.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
$data->read('InOut.xls');

$res = $data->sheets;
echo "<pre>";print_r($data->sheets);//exit;
```

but the file with password protected is not get readable

Can anyone help to me to do this ?

Comment: Open the password protected file save as new filename without password protection then use the new file for import.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty That's not a solid solution but a workaround.

Comment: @Abhik without password it's worked find,but i want to import a password protected file but that file is not get readable

Comment: Is there any other to know the excel file is password protected or not? like by calling ajax call from the button click of html and then navigate to php file